# "Accept-Ranges" header is set to "none" when a spring boot app is hosted in remote VM. It is set to "bytes" when hosted locally

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, http-headers, accept-ranges

I have a spring boot application which needs to serve range requests for resuming downloads. Things works fine when this spring boot app is hosted in local windows machine and "Accept-Ranges" header is set to "bytes" by default. But when the same application is hosted in a remote virtual machine running windows, "Accept-Ranges" header is set to "none" by default and resuming download is not working. What can be the issue here?

```
>curl -I http://localhost:8080

HTTP/1.1 200
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 36121548
Date: Tue, 14 Sep 2021 13:00:19 GMT


>curl -I http://{IPofRemoteVM}:8080

HTTP/1.1 200
Accept-Ranges:  none
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 36121548
Date: Tue, 14 Sep 2021 13:00:23 GMT
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm running into the same problem.